# ObjectDisposedException in VS 2013 XAML editor (+ Blend)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, telerik, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a WP8 project and I'm using VS 2013 with Telerik WP8 controls, ReSharper, Windows Phone Controls Toolkit and a couple of other references. (The reason I list the extensions is that I read some posts about references causing similar issues)

Quite often the visual XAML editor throws the following error:

```
ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'NativeObject'.

at System.Windows.DependencyObject.MS.Internal.IManagedPeerBase.get_NativeObject()
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.DependencyObject_SetParentForInheritanceContextOnly(DependencyObject doh, DependencyObject parentDO)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(DependencyProperty property)
at MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.InvalidateProperty(IntPtr nativeTarget, UInt32 propertyId)
```

Although I understand what the exception means I would like to know (exactly) what causes it. I already enabled logging for VS2013 using the /log cmd line parameter but the log doesn't show anything.

Does anybody know what the issues might be or maybe point me into the right direction? I also appreciate any tip for digging into V2013 to find out more about the error to find out the root cause (log, debugging, ...)?

Regards, 
Stephan

Comment: You're not alone. The same thing happens to me. Did you figure out the cause of it yet?

Comment: Not yet but I'm currently in contact with Telerik support for one related issue.

Comment: I found another user in the internet who blogged about that issue and he too thinks that the root cause are the Telerik controls. I'll open a support ticket today and update this thread if I have any updates.

Comment: I am also running into this issue while using Telerik controls, has there been any update?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. However, I just looked at [link](http://www.monkeyslaps.com/vs-issue-designer-failing/) again (the other user I mentioned above) and he pointed out that his issue was basically related to his view model. I'll need to have a look at this closer to figure out whether it helps. On Telerik side they weren't able to reproduce the issue. Remote debugging VS didn't work either. The remote debugger didn't catch the exception for some reason.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I'm still reopening the issue on Teleriks side by still providing more stack traces and sample programs but they are not able to reproduce that issue. Not sure what's different on my environment compared to theirs.

Comment: With VS2013 Update 2 and the latest Telerik controls I don't get these issues anymore. However, I'm still doubtfully due to the last months with these issues.